# Is single page website bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, htaccess, url-rewriting, google-index

Suppose I have a website for a company which I want to SEO.

Think of two scenarios:

1) There is only `index.php`, and for /about /contact sections I do it like this:
`index.php?what=about` , `index.php?what=contact` etc. and I change the url using .htaccess, so the links become `www.company.com/about` , `www.company.com/contact` and every page has unique content of course.

2) Everything has their own page. i.e. :

- http

  - index.php
  - about.php
  - contact.php

I think that these two scenarios are the same, if they have the same content. I mean Google should not care about the server-end right? Or am I wrong? Please inform me before I go any further :)

Thanks !

Comment: Also lots more discussions about this > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=single+page+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Additionally if use htaccess to break down the pages then its not a single page site, but ideally you should just divide the pages using PHP/SQL or Static.